# Loading large amounts of data from SQL Server database in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm using `csvhelper` to create a `.csv` file.

This is my code:

```
    public async Task LoadLargeDataToCsvFile(string pFileName, string pSql)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(pSql, GetSqlConnection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(pFileName, false, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            using (CsvWriter csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer))
            {
                    csvWriter.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";
                    csvWriter.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CChevalPropertiesMap>();

                using (SqlDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                {
                    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                                csvWriter.WriteField(reader[i]);
                        }

                        await csvWriter.NextRecordAsync();
                    }

                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This code takes a long time to execute and yet I think it is well done.

This is the call:

```
await Task.Run(()=> cConnection.LoadLargeDataFromSqlToCsvFile(args[0], args[1]));
```

or

```
IAsyncResult result;

result = Task.Run(()=> cConnection.LoadLargeDataFromSqlToCsvFile(args[0], args[1]));

while (!result.IsCompleted)
{
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

I have 60000 rows in the table and 10 columns.

Comment: It is likely that the SQL query takes a long time regardless of the csvhelper part of the code. Have you tried to run the SQL query on its own and see how long it takes in SSMS or your SQL manager of choice? There are lots of options for improving SQL performance if it still takes a long time.

Comment: In ssms, the request takes a minute

Comment: @ChentalGraciaMigra - have you tried loading a table instead of writing to stream to see where the problem might be? some thing like this:using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess).ConfigureAwait(false))
                    {
                        dt.Load(reader);
                    }

Comment: @ChentalGraciaMigra - why do you need call via Task.Run() instead of result = await cConnection.LoadLargeDataFromSqlToCsvFile(args[0], args[1])  ?

Comment: it's one or other. 
But I understood. it is not the loading but the reading of the product file which takes time, more than two hours.